# SQL - Converting datetime to month(full name) year only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert a dateTime value to Month Year.

I want them like January 2021, March 2021, April 2021.

My current solution works, but only get the first 3 characters of the month

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET AccountingPeriod = replace(right(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106), 8), ' ', ' ');
```

I am getting **Oct 2021**, but I would like to get **October 2021**.

Comment: You should **never** use `varchar` without specifying the length.

Comment: Can't your app/presentation layer do this? Why do you want to store bulky, language-specific month names in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATENAME()` :

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), ' ', YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any standard date/datetime formats that will get you this (using `CONVERT`).

When there is not standard format available that directly supports your use case, personally, I prefer to use `DATENAME` function for this in SQL Server. It is a very easy function that allows you to pull different pieces of the date/datetime for the purpose of display. Using this, you can pull in the discrete pieces you need and then place them together in a single string using `CONCAT`.

Something like this would work for your situation:

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()),' ',DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function like below

```
    select format(getdate(), N'Y', 'en-us')
```

[image]

Comment: For onesy-twosy stuff `FORMAT()` is fine, but because [it is absolutely horrendous at scale](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but), we just shouldn't ever recommend it IMHO.